# Update all rows but one using SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table like so

```
+-------------------------------------+
| Description | ID  |  Show(1 or 0)   |
+-------------------------------------+
```

I have a bunch of entries with the same description but one has an ID of null. I have to set show on all the rows without the null to 0 but only if they have more than rows 2 of the same description. I am new to SQL and I have around 50K rows so I would rather not do it manually.

USA 987655 1 - changed to 0

USA 987658 1 - changed to 0

USA 987617 1 - changed to 0

USA 989876 null - unchanged

CAN 767655 1 - not changed

CAN 957655 1 - not changed

have tried:

```
UPDATE  test1 t1,
    (
    SELECT  id, description, show AS mid
    FROM    test1 ti
    GROUP BY
            description
    ) tm
SET     show = 0
WHERE   t1.description= tm.description
    AND id is not null;
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: select ID from table left join same table where something matches something else and something is null... Been answered so many times.

Comment: for example on the last part of the record above has this row `EUR 666661 0`, do I need to change it to 1? or not since it has only one `EUR`?

Comment: no, only if it has more than 2 entries

Comment: ok, but why is that `USA` will be change to `0` and `CAN` remains its value for `show`?

Comment: because there is a date column that will expire one of them.

Comment: `date`? oh i see, maybe you can edit the records above to avoid confusion and also to give more information on the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a correlated sub-query. I haven't tested this, so use with caution. But something like this might be what you're after.

```
UPDATE
  some_table st1
  JOIN (
    SELECT st2.description, count(*) c
    FROM some_table st2
    WHERE
      st1.description = st1.description AND
      st1.id IS NOT NULL AND
      st2.id IS NOT NULL
    GROUP by st2.description
    HAVING c > 1
  ) AS tmp ON tmp.description = st1.description
SET st1.show = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the final answer but could help you a lot ( i guess)

execute this query to see which ones should be updated from 0 to 1

```
SELECT description, COUNT(*) as "Same Description" FROM table
WHERE id <> null
GROUP BY description
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
```